# Elasticsearch add values of similar keys across documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch 6.8 (or 7) I have documents with differing keys and I want to add the values across across all.  For example:

```
{"ok":10, "mn":12, "ca":84},
{"tx":34, "mn":20, "ca":100},
{"tx":10, "ma":10, "ca":100}
```

I want (in some form):

```
 {"ok":10, "mn":42,"ca":284, "tx":44}
```

My end goal is to graph the sum value across each available key.

Is this workable in the current format?  Is there a better format other than using a single document for each key?  (The full key domain set will not be known)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that each new line of what you've shared is a new document.

And I don't think there is a way to sum for all possible fields via query. This may have to be handled at application layer where you pull all the respective fields and then formulate the query as mentioned below.

Assuming the fields are numeric in nature, you can use a [Sum Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) on each of the fields in the following way:

**Query Request:**

```
POST you_index_name/_search
{
  "size": 0,                         <----- To ensure you see only aggregation results.
  "aggs": {
    "sum_ok": {
      "sum": {                       <----- sum aggregation
        "field": "ok"
      }
    },
    "sum_mn": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "mn"
      }
    },
    "sum_ca": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "ca"
      }
    },
    "sum_tx": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "tx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should give you, well not exactly as what you like but close to it as below:

**Aggregation Result**

```
{
  "took" : 432,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "sum_ok" : {
      "value" : 10.0
    },
    "sum_ca" : {
      "value" : 284.0
    },
    "sum_mn" : {
      "value" : 32.0.       <------ Note that this is 32 based on data you've shared
    },
    "sum_tx" : {
      "value" : 44.0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, marking as correct cause it's as close as I've found.